# Error handling with "err" in C: What codes should I use?

Tags: c, error-handling

The man page for `err` and `errx` states the following syntax:

- `void err(int eval, const char *fmt, ...);`
- `void errx(int eval, const char *fmt, ...);`

Obviously `const char *fmt` is the format string and `...` contains the parameteres for it (just like `printf`). I know that `eval` is a code you assign to the error. Since the man page doesn't say anything more specific about the `eval` parameter, I was wondering: 
Is there a rule/ convention, which specifies what error codes should be assigned for specific errors, or it is a choice of the programmer, who is writing the code, to write whatever `eval` value they deem necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page on my Ubuntu (GNU/Linux) system:

> The `err()`, `verr()`, `errx()`, and `verrx()` functions do not return, but exit with the value of the argument `eval`.

So it's a value that you would pass to `exit`.

If you want to be portable, C defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

That said, you should have no problems returning a number from 0 to 127, with 0 meaning success. The meaning of those numbers is up to you, but usually go up in severity. For example, `grep` returns 0 if a match is found, 1 if a match isn't found, and 2 if an error occurred.